# file option not working in custom options for product import from csv

Tags: magento-1.7, import, custom-options

I am facing a very strange problem with custom options import for a product.
The custom option with file type is not creating in the product. I have also checked the database for this. There are no rows inserted for the file type whether the other options with other types are saved and also showing in backend and frontend. 
Also there is another problem that when i import the products they do not show on the frontend because the Website is not set for the product. I didn't find any option to set the website for the product and i have do it manually from the actions dropdown using Update Attributes and setting the product to the website.
Please someone help me as it very urgent.

Comment: It seems you are describing 2 issues here. For the first one, the option fields. Are there any errors in the Magento error logs that might point to a cause? You can also try and disable all 3th party extensions and see if the issue originates from one of them.

For your second problem, what kind of extension do you use for importing?

When 2 problems are not related please submit 2 different questions instead of one. That way it's more clear what the issue is. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Both of the issues are for one csv import. I am using magento's default csv with custom options for importing products. Just figured out the solution for the first problem of file option in the csv. Now I want to know if there is any option to set default website or store for product while uploading products through csv

Comment: Ah ok, my mistake. I've never used dataflow but the attribute is called `website_ids` in the code and accepts an array with website ID's so that might point you in the right direction

Comment: Is this option also added in the magento default csv?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't use dataflow myself but you can try

Answer (score 3):

Finally find the solution for the problem with the csv after digging deep into the code.

Posting it here if anybody needs the same.

For the file upload problem go to

**app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php**

and on the line no. 684 uncomment the line

**'file'      => array('price', 'sku', 'file_extension', 'image_size_x', 'image_size_y'),**

I don't understand why this is commented by default in magento.

And the products were not showing on the frontend just because of the indexing. After reindexing all the product tables I got all the products on the frontend

Thanks